# What does BGP Path Attribute Type 18 refer to?

Tags: networking, routes, network-protocols, packet, bgp

Does anyone know what Path Attribute Type 18 refers to and how to parse it?  The best I can understand is that it is a new AGGREGATOR (type 7) and I'm assuming that it's reading the new AS32 format, but that's not cutting it because I can't parse this packet.  Is there an RFC that describes how this works...is it something special that CISCO or another network vendor introduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: attribute 18 is AS4_AGGREGATOR which is described in RFC 4893. It carries a 4-octet AS number. I have seen UPDATEs with that attribute generated by Cisco and Juniper routers and never noticed anything unusual that isn't clear from the RFC. If you post a hex-dump of that packet which is giving you trouble I could attempt a decode for you...